# What parts do I need to RMA? I made a TON of careless mistakes upgrading. Motherboard fried for sure, not sure what else

Tags: motherboard, upgrade, power-supply, post, cmos

Ok, so I have a asrock extreme3gen3, core i5, 5 case fans, 2ssd, 2hdd, 1cdrom.

I have screwed up so many times doing this upgrade, I need some help sorting it out.

I had a 560ti which I overclocked in the (secondary) pci-e port, computer worked fine.

Then I upgraded to a 770, a 1050w power supply (and got a 27 inch monitor, QQ).

I realized I had my raid card in the primary pci-e slot (just a pci card).

Then I plugged in a pci-e supplementary power adapted into my motherboards 8pin 12v slot. I daisy chained all the fans to 1 fan power pin set on the motherboard, and hooked up all the power adapters just carelessly and wrong (probably). The only thing I don't think I did was put power into a fan output pin thing. Also, I originally hooked up the 770 in the secondary pci-e slot (not sure if it matters). I don't think I put the 12v into the pci-e slot on the graphics card, but who knows I am an idiot.

So I turn the pc on, nothing happens, I make sure the cords are snug, and then it the fans spin like 3 rotations when I turn it on and then nothing happens. Keep doing some things and tried it a few more times (I know, the worst idea).

I removed all the expansion cards.

So basically now if everything is plugged in exactly correctly according to the manuals and specification sheets, absolutely nothing happens when I press the power button on the pc or the motherboard. I tried setting the jumper to reset the c-mos with no effect.

I then tried plugging in my old power supply to the two motherboard ports (the big one and the 8pin), and still absolutely nothing happens when I press the power button on the motherboard or the case.

What parts should I start RMAing? I also have a digital power tester my brother gave me, but I am not sure how to use it.

I really hope it's just the motherboard and maybe the power supply.

Thanks,

Comment: Also my home lights flickered when the fans started and stopped and I was using a surge protector if that has any relevence

Comment: Uh... none. RMA is not appropriate for parts that you fried yourself.

Comment: Ok. Well can you please provide me some helpful information as to guidance of what to do? I have printed and reviewed the manuals to the components, but I am afraid of doing something else stupid to be honest

Answer (score 3):

Just stop. Get someone who knows what they're doing to take over. Even if we could tell you exactly what to do, there's a skill to knowing how to do it and knowing what looks right and what doesn't. You're clearly operating outside your field of competence, so please stop.

Comment: Thanks friend. I was excited and sleep deprived and didnt think I needed to look at specifications. I built the computer originally and overclocked it for a year before I did this

Comment: Also the comical thing is I am about to start graduate school for computer engineering

Comment: Even so, there is a skill to doing these things, and in troubleshooting your own mistakes - many of us have been sleep deprived in our computing careers, but still know what we're doing regardless of mental state.   P.S. Good luck with the computer engineering course, hope you enjoy the experience.

Comment: I understand that. I am just asking for some guidance in the right direction to determine if my cpu ram snd drives are destroyed.  I could test them in another computer. I just ask for help because I am very upset about how stupid I am and am becoming too stressed to think well. I probably won't sleep again because of this.

Comment: @user231416 - Process of Elimination.  You have ruled out the power supply.  So its either the CPU, Memory, Motherboard.  Purchase some cheap memory and rule out the memory.  Your Ivybridge i3 has an integrated graphics use that for now.

Comment: okay man I figured it out I'm going to go buy a new motherboard test that out and if it doesn't work I'm going to try the components individually in my friends computer.